# PHP7 set_exception_handler and set_error_handler callbacks are mixed

Tags: php, error-handling, exception, php-7

**Seems i found some bug in to php7.0.3 but i'm not sure probably issue is at my side so i decided to write here first**

i have recently updated my server `php` version to  to `php7.0.3`, and of course there was errors about deprecated method etc i was fixing them one by one till i come to this one

> Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Debug::_exceptionHandler() must be an instance of Exception, instance of Error given in SomePath\Debug.php:518 Stack trace: #0 [internal function]: Debug::_exceptionHandler(Object(Error)) #1 {main} thrown

i checked `Debug` class and found there `set_exception_handler` and  `set_error_handler` calls in `function enable()`

```
public static function enable( ..some params.. ){
    ...
    set_exception_handler(array(__CLASS__, '_exceptionHandler'));
    set_error_handler(array(__CLASS__, '_errorHandler'));
}

// where _exceptionHandler function defined as
public static function _exceptionHandler(Exception $exception)
{ ... }

// and _errorHandler defined as
public static function _errorHandler($severity, $message, $file, $line, $context)
{ ... }
```

Actually error is clear for me it tells that it can't pass `Error` type object to `_exceptionHandler` as it excepts `Exception` type, but the **Question** is **Why it trying to pass it to `_exceptionHandler` instead `_errorHandler` as it also defined ? is it bug or i'm missing something in definition of `error` and `exception` handlers ?**

*Note: i tried to play with `set_error_handler` pass it as second argument `E_ALL` etc but noting helps...*

I also got error which was thrown and should be handled by `_errorHandler` but instead handled by `_exceptionHandler` was

> Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function set_magic_quotes_runtime() in SomePath...

Can someone help me with this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The exception hierarchy in PHP 7 has changed, if you take a look at the [manual page](http://php.net/set_exception_handler) for `set_exception_handler` you will notice:

> Since PHP 7, most errors are reported by throwing Error exceptions, which will be caught by the handler as well. Both Error and Exception implements the Throwable interface. This is the handler signature since PHP 7:

```
void handler ( Throwable $ex );
```

Details of the changes to exception hierarchy in PHP 7 can be found [here](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/throwable-interface).

Comment: Actually i checked `set_exception_handler` page and did noticed that message, now i got it and understand the reason thank you